# Can't define variable for link to edit page

Tags: php, mysql, variables, model-view-controller, syntax

I am building a blog and trying to create a link that goes to an edit page. My database table blog_posts has the following variables: postDate, postID, userId, postDesc. They all display correctly on my render page for each blog record.

I now am trying to create a link to my edit page and having trouble getting my $blog['edit'] variable below to work.  I have tried defining it in both the Model and controller - no luck.

Thanks for any help.

CONTROLLER:

```
public function indexAction() {
        $request = $this->getRequest();

         $this->view->blogs = Blog_Model_Blog::findAll();

        $blogs =  Blog_Model_Blog::getAllBlogEntries();
        if($blogs) {
            foreach($blogs AS $blog) {
                $blog['edit'] = WM_Router::create($this->getRequest()->getBaseUrl() . '?module=blog&controller=admin&action=edit&id=' . $blog['postID']);
                $this->view->blogs[] = $blog;
            }
        }
    }
```

MODEL:

```
        public static function getAllBlogEntries() {
            $db = JO_Db::getDefaultAdapter();
            $query= $db->select ()
                -> from ('blog_posts',array('*'))
                -> order ('blog_posts.postDate DESC');

            return $db->fetchAll($query);
        }

        public static function findAll($_callbackQuery = null) {
            $blog = parent::findAll($_callbackQuery);
            return $blog;
        }
```

VIEW:

```
    <?php if ($this->blogs) { ?>
        <?php foreach ($this->blogs AS $blog) { ?>
            <tr id="<?php echo $blog->postID; ?>">
                <td><?php echo $blog->postID; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $blog->userId; ?></td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href="<?php echo $blog['edit'];?>"><img title="<?php echo $this->translate('Edit');?>" alt="" class="tooltip" src="cms/admin/images/edit.png"></a>
                </td>

            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you show us a code of your single blog class?

Comment: @zajonc not sure what you mean my single blog class.

Comment: Do you have any php code for class of single $blog object? If not - can you show a var_dump for $blog in controller just before you try to add an 'edit' element?